# How to determine what Frameworks IPhone App uses?

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I was wondering what is the way to get a list of Frameworks used by iPhone App? Apple is doing it during AppStore approval process. I would like to know if certain games are using Open GL ES...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terminal, run:

```
"otool -L <binary>"
```

I assume you have access to the binary. 
This will show you all the libs/frameworks it links against.

PS: the binary is the actual Mach-O file, not the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if a game on iOS has a lot of things moving onscreen at once without horrible performance—i.e. at a frame rate at or higher than that which you can perceive—it's using OpenGL. Core Animation and Quartz aren't fast enough yet to be viable tools for that.